# A dilemma in a lemma regarding Hexagonal Fuzzy approximation of parabolic fuzzy number

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations, fuzziness

I was reading [Nayagam & Murugan - Hexagonal fuzzy approximation of fuzzy numbers and its applications in MCDM](https://doi.org/10.1007/s40747-020-00242-4) paper regarding hexagonal fuzzy approximation. In that, the statement of Lemma 3.1 and its proof seem misleading. Like, in the lemma it is said that the solutions for $h_1=\frac{7T(p_2-p_1)}{10}$ and $h_2=p_2-p_1-Tp_2-Tp_1$ that satisfy the equations (3), (4), (7), (8), (11), (12), (15), (16) are obtained by solving for the extremely long expression given in that lemma. Again, in the proof, it is said that we get $h_1=\frac{7T(p_2-p_1)}{10}$ and $h_2=p_2-p_1-Tp_2-Tp_1$ by solving equations (3), (4). So, I am unable to come to a conclusion regarding the correctness of the lemma.

On the one hand, by solving equations (3), (4)  by using a CAS like Wolfram/MATLAB/Maple, I get very different expressions for $h_1$, $h_2$ than those given in the paper; on the other hand, substituting the given value of $h_1,h_2$ in the equation (4), as stated in the proof does not give the expression given in the statement of the lemma. So, what is the Lemma 3.1 and its proof precisely trying to say. Any light on this matter?